# Bash and For loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have two files with the following lines:

File1:

[2011-09-21 11:27:44.663] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260540762613|50498692776|4|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:44.906] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260643402689|50494792676|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:44.907] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260644572692|50497855449|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.334] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260649992694|50496364022|*902|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.437] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260650582695|50497646930|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|516
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|605
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.733] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260623002676|50499119706|2|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.755] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260653182698|50496437811|*702|Activation|0|600

File2:

[2011-09-21 11:27:44.663] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260540762613|50498692776|4|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:44.906] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260643402689|50494792676|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:44.907] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260644572692|50497855449|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.334] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260649992694|50496364022|*902|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.437] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260650582695|50497646930|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|504
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|605
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.639] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260651372696|50494876344|*702|Activation|0|600
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.733] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260623002676|50499119706|2|Activation|0|504
[2011-09-21 11:27:45.755] EXT-RESPONSE|13166260653182698|50496437811|*702|Activation|0|600

I want to read both file on a shell script and get some values... I have created a For in order to work with both file...

Here is the script..

```
#!/bin/bash

UD_GW1='/root/Lab/UD_GW1'
UD_GW2='/root/Lab/UD_GW2'
i='1'
while [ $i -le "2" ]; do
for e in  $UD_GW1 $UD_GW2 ; do
echo "TABLE USSD_GW$i"  
echo "START_SAMPLE_PERIOD"
while read numcodigo; do
cantidad_uniq=`tail -n 60000 $e | egrep "EXT-RESPONSE" | cut -d '|' -f 7 | egrep -v ^$  | egrep "$numcodigo" | wc -l`
echo "$numcodigo".Metric" "=" $numcodigo"
echo "CantCod."$numcodigo"Metric "=" $cantidad_uniq"
done #fin while read numcodigo;   
echo "END_SAMPLE_PERIOD"
echo "END_TABLE"
let i=$i+1
done
done
```

And i need something like:

```
TABLE USSD_GW1
START_SAMPLE_PERIOD
600.Metric = 600
CantCod.600Metric = 8
518.Metric = 518
CantCod.518Metric = 0
504.Metric = 504
CantCod.504Metric = 0
516.Metric = 516
CantCod.516Metric = 1
527.Metric = 527
CantCod.527Metric = 0
END_SAMPLE_PERIOD
END_TABLE
TABLE USSD_GW2
START_SAMPLE_PERIOD
600.Metric = 600
CantCod.600Metric = 7
518.Metric = 518
CantCod.518Metric = 0
504.Metric = 504
CantCod.504Metric = 2
516.Metric = 516
CantCod.516Metric = 0
527.Metric = 527
CantCod.527Metric = 0
END_SAMPLE_PERIOD
END_TABLE
```

However when i run my script i got:

```
TABLE USSD_GW1
START_SAMPLE_PERIOD
600.Metric = 600
CantCod.600Metric = 8
518.Metric = 518
CantCod.518Metric = 0
504.Metric = 504
CantCod.504Metric = 0
516.Metric = 516  
CantCod.516Metric = 1
527.Metric = 527
CantCod.527Metric = 0
END_SAMPLE_PERIOD
END_TABLE 
TABLE USSD_GW2
START_SAMPLE_PERIOD
END_SAMPLE_PERIOD
END_TABLE
```

Please any help would be great....

Thanks,

Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for your script. Why don't you use array for files & also move your display logic to a function?
The advantage of using an array will be that you can easily extend it to multiple files (more than 2 in current case)
Separating the display logic into a function will help you debug & change the logic easily

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #First param is the file to read to check for codes
 #Second param is the file to read the codes from 
 function display_info()
 {
    #Your display logic is here...
    for numcodigo in `cat $2`
    do
     cantidad_uniq=`tail -n 60000 $1 | egrep "EXT-RESPONSE" | cut -d '|' -f 7 | egrep -v ^$  | egrep "$numcodigo" | wc -l`
     echo "$numcodigo".Metric" "=" $numcodigo"
     echo "CantCod."$numcodigo"Metric "=" $cantidad_uniq"
    done 
 }

 #Main operation
 #Array elements are space separated
 #newline is used only to make it more readable & easier to add new array elements
 file_list=(
  /root/Lab/UD_GW1 
  /root/Lab/UD_GW2
  )
 index=1
 for file in ${file_list[@]}
 do
     echo "TABLE USSD_GW$index"  
     echo "START_SAMPLE_PERIOD"
     #Pass file to read from the list as first param
     #Pass file to read the codes to check from command line argument as second param
     display_info $file $1 
     echo "END_SAMPLE_PERIOD"
     echo "END_TABLE"
     let "index++"
 done
```

Hope this helps!
PS: BTW how does your output have 518 etc which are not in the files? Are you checking for tokens from elsewhere?
EDIT:
Please run this script as `./<scripts_name> codes.txt`
There are alternative to achieve what you need, but this is just one of the ways!

Comment: Hi thank for reply.. but i got the same.. i using the same logic in the function display_info () However is the same output...  this is the logic that i am using>  while read numcodigo; do
 cantidad_uniq=`tail -n 60000 $1 | egrep "EXT-RESPONSE" | cut -d '|' -f 7 | egrep -v ^$  | egrep "$numcodigo" | wc -l`
 salida1=$?
 echo "$numcodigo".Metric" "=" $numcodigo"
 echo "CantCod."$numcodigo"Metric "=" $cantidad_uniq"
 done ... is something wrong with this logic?... and yes I have a file with the codes... that is readed in the while loop.

Comment: Could you please tell us how you are running your script? And how exactly is the file with codes look like (many be just a few lines)?

Comment: sure... ./parser.sh < codes.txt ... the codes.txt is like: 600
518
504
516
527
(one code per line)
what is wrong here?

Comment: The problem in your logic is that you read the codes.txt only once & that lasts only for one single loop i.e. only for the first file. I will edit my response to provide one of the ways to support your requirement

Comment: ok, thanks but for: for numcodigo in `cat $1`  what would be the right expression to this: cantidad_uniq=`tail -n 60000 $e | egrep "EXT-RESPONSE" | cut -d '|' -f 7 | egrep -v ^$  | egrep "$numcodigo" | wc -l` , because $e does not exist

Comment: I have updated the response... Please let me know if there is problem :)

Comment: thanks.... for the input.. it's working now... if you come to Chile someday... i will invite the beers... :)

Comment: In bash functions parameters are passed as `function_name param1 param2 ...` translated as `$n`, `n` being index i.e. `param1` becomes `$1` in function & so on. codes.txt is argument passed to the script which becomes `$1` in your *main* operation section. Function logic is to search through file passed as first param `$1` for codes in file passed as second param `$2`. As codes.txt is passed as first argument as file to read codes from (`$1` in script) it is passed to function as second param. Ofc the first param is file to search for which is nothing but `$file` from `${file_list[@]}` array.

Answer (score 0):

remove the while loop and the references to i.  You only need the for loop.

Alternatively you could remove the for loop, assigning `e=/root/Lab/UD_GW$i`

You should also write the inner loop as `cat $e | while read numcodigo; do`

Comment: Thanks for your help. it does not work.... and i need to print "TABLE USSD_GW1", "TABLE USSD_GW2" that's way the while loop...